# How do I solve a quadratic (parabola) inequality with complex roots?

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers, quadratics

For example, let's take the inequality $0<x^2+2x+4$. 
[The real solutions to the inequality are shown in the graph.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58wqj.png) 
If we look at the graph, all real solutions would work for this inequality.

However, how would I express the complex numbers that also answer the question? 
In other words, what are the real and complex solutions for this inequality.

Comment: If $z,w\in\mathbb{C}$, what do you mean by $z>w$? The complex numbers cannot be totally ordered.

Comment: Ok, so is all real numbers the solution, or is there more?

Comment: No. Because complex numbers can't be ordered, they cannot satisfy inequalities like this.

Answer (score 2):

An inequation like $z>0$ where $z$ is a complex number is meaningless because you cannot compare complex numbers.

You can modify the question and for instance ask $\Re(z)>0$, which is allowed as the real part of a complex number is... real.

Now let $x:=u+iv$ and let us solve

$$\Re(x^2+2x+4)=\Re(u^2-v^2+2u+4+i(2uv+2v))=(u+1)^2-v^2+2>0.$$

The solution is a portion of the complex plane delimited by an equilaterl hyperbola centered at $(-1,0)$.

But this answers an arbitrary restatement of the problem :-)

Answer (score 0):

Compute
$$x^2+2x+4=x^2+2x+1+3=(x+1)^2+3,$$ which is greater than $0$ for any real number $x.$